# define a style for a button in code behind UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I tried to apply a style for my button in the code behind,like this:

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;

```
 MenuButton2.Style = ButtonStyle();

     private Style ButtonStyle()
            {
                string xaml =
                  "<Style  " +
"xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' " +
                    "xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' " +
                    "xmlns:d = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008' " +
                    "TargetType='Button'>" +
                     "<Setter Property='Foreground' Value='#e6e6e6'/>" +
                   " < Setter Property = 'Template' >" +
                    " < Setter.Value >" +
                         "< ControlTemplate TargetType = 'Button' >" +
                              "< Grid >" +
                                  "< VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups >" +
                                      "< VisualStateGroup x: Name = 'CommonStates' >" +
                                            "< VisualState x: Name = 'Normal' />" +
                                              "< VisualState x: Name = 'PointerOver' >" +
                                                   " < Storyboard >" +
                                                        "< ColorAnimation Duration = '0' To = '#e6e6e6' Storyboard.TargetProperty = '(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)' Storyboard.TargetName = 'Button' />" +
                                                           "</ Storyboard >" +
                                                       "</ VisualState >" +
                                                       "< VisualState x: Name = 'Pressed' >" +
                                                            " < Storyboard >" +
                                                                    " < ColorAnimation Duration = '0' To = '#e6e6e6' Storyboard.TargetProperty = '(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)' Storyboard.TargetName = 'Button' />" +
                                                                        "< ColorAnimation Duration = '0' To = '#e6e6e6' Storyboard.TargetProperty = '(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)' Storyboard.TargetName = 'Content' />" +
                                                                           "</ Storyboard > " +
                                                                      " </ VisualState >" +
                                                                  " </ VisualStateGroup >" +
                                                              " </ VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups >" +
                                                               "< Grid >" +
                                                                  " < Rectangle x: Name = 'Button' Stroke = 'Transparent' Fill = 'Transparent' Margin = '0' />" +
                                                                          " < ContentPresenter x: Name = 'Content' />" +
                                                                         "</ Grid >" +
                                                                       " </ Grid >" +
                                                                 "</ ControlTemplate >" +
                                                            " </ Setter.Value >" +
                                                        " </ Setter >" +
                                                          "</Style>";
                return (Style)Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xaml);
            }
```

but I have a problem when I execute my app,this is the error I get:

An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in App.exe but was not handled in user code
 WinRT information: illegal qualified name character [Line: 1 Position: 262]
 Additional information: The text associated with this error code is not found.

thanks for help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are trying to do this versus creating a resource dictionary?  I have never seen this approach.

Define your Style in a resource dictionary and give it a `x:Key="MyStyleName"`

Load your dictionary in app.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/MyStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Reference your style anywhere you want:

```
myStyle = (Style)App.Current.Resource["MyStyleName"];
```

Use it like: `MenuButton2.Style = myStyle;`

This would be the more conventional approach to using a syle on your control.